# PHP Active Record Debugging

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Hi everyone I'm getting pissed off with a seemingly easy table join, but I can't tell what is going wrong since I don't know what the query is. Is there a way to debug Active Records? I found one [here](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Connection#var%24last_query), but how do I get access to the connection object?

The real issue is I'm trying to pull up all projects that a user is associated with (relation ship is in a joiner table)

projects table -> user_projects table -> users  table

```
Project::find('all', array(
    'select' => 'user_projects.id, title, description, last_update',
    'conditions' => array('user_projects.user_id = ?', $user_id),
    'joins' => 'LEFT JOIN user_projects ON projects.id = user_project.project_id'
));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I discovered the answer to my own issue somehow, to get the last query:

`Model::connection()->last_query`